# Reloading recyclerView with previous data between activities

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created an app that has a Leaderboard it in.

The Leaderboard consists of 3 categories: Top rank, Most sharing, Most info.

[image]

In each category (tab), there is a recyclerView that loaded 25 results each from `firestore`.

What happens is that every time a user opens this activity it reads 75 documents which is pretty much and I'm trying to avoid it.

Is there any way that when a user starts the activity for the first time it will load these 75 documents but if he starts the activity 5 minutes later, for example, it will just display the same results as previously without reading 75 documents from `firestore` again?

Each recyclerView is loaded by using:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( getApplicationContext() );
rv_TopRank.setLayoutManager( mLayoutManager );
rv_TopRank.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator() );

private void showTopRanked() {
    usersID.clear();
    usersName.clear();
    usersResult.clear();

    db.collectionGroup( "UserData" ).orderBy( "rank", Query.Direction.DESCENDING ).limit( AppConstants.LEADERBOARD_TO_LOAD ).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener( queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if (document != null) {
                        usersID.add( document.getId() );
                        usersName.add( document.getString( "username" ) );
                        usersResult.add( document.getDouble( "rank" ) );
                    }
                }
                leaderBoardAdapter = new LeaderBoardAdapter( usersID, usersName, usersResult, 0 );
                rv_TopRank.setAdapter( leaderBoardAdapter );
                leaderBoardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } );
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I can suggest you to setup a room database to store data locally for the recycler view and also a **shared preference** to store the time the data was fetched and then you can check at onCreate if the shared preference stored time is more than 5 min you can fetch the database from firestore.  hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use Android's [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) to save this data locally, and update it only when you deem it necessary as opposed to every time the app is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

In the `onCreate()` method of the activity, read the date from Calendar and save it in `sharedPreferences` as the date of last update and then check to see if the current date is not equal to the date of last update before you query from firebase.

Something like this:

```
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

val today = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
val lastUpdateDay = sharedPref.getInt("lastUpdateDay", 0)

if (today != lastUpdateDay) {
    //THE LOCAL DATA IS OLD SO IT NEEDS TO BE UPDATED FROM FIREBASE THEREFORE:
   
    //Query and show Firebase database data
    //Store the data locally (Either in a database or again in sharedPref)
    //and save `today` to sharedPref in the onSuccess() block like so:
    sharedPref.edit().putInt("lastUpdateDay", today).apply()
} else {
    //THE LOCAL DATA IS UP-TO-DATE SO NO NEED FOR A FIREBASE QUERY

    //Load the data you have stored locally the day before
}
```

I'm sorry the code is in Kotlin. it's just to give you an idea.

Comment: But if today!= lastUpdateDay, how do I make sure that the recyclerView still shows the previous results? It will probably just show empty recyclerView no? I mean when the activity starts the recyclerview is empty.

Comment: If `today != lastUpdateDay`, it means you wanna load new data from firebase and show it. If `today == lastUpdateDay`, it means the user has already checked the results today so the available data (which you have stored locally) is up-to-date and you just load the data from the local database and not firestore. So basically the data is only synced once a day this way.